# How to use ng-controller within custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

i am making the custom directive and setting ng-controller within the directive and want to get the scope of ng-controller in that directive.

```
app.directive('customDirective',['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
       scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000,
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
              element.attr("ng-controller", mycontroller);
              element.removeAttr("custom-directive"); 
              $rootScope.dir = scope; //want to set the scope of mycontroller
        }

}]);
```

How to set the scope of mycontroller in rootScope.dir?

Comment: please fix your directive code. A line is missing after function definition and before scope: true

Comment: The scope would only come into existence once the controller is loaded for directive, so you cannot access it from compile. I am even not sure why would someone want to do such a thing?

Comment: Hi Chandermani, This is not the actual code, it is only sample of actual thing that i want. I have the controller predefined, and i want to user the data of scope of the controller outside of my directive by geting it from rootScope.How to fixed it

Comment: Hi  idursun, Dont care about the line ..... Please clear the concept and how to set the scope of controller in rootScope